# port 3306 is closed on my website how can i open it?

Tags: mysql, web, vb.net

I have a vb.net desktop app.. and I need to insert some data to database on my website. when it's try to add data I get this Error: " Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts "

when I try Other IP shared IP from Other website, it's work. but it's not for my website..

I Checked it on this https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it's give me that Port 3306 is closed on "My IP Address"

this is My connection string look like:

Server=Mywebsite IP;Port=3306;Database=databasename;Uid=username;Pwd=password;

can you help me with that.. thanks..

Comment: Databases should *never* have open ports on the public internet. It is likely that the database is deliberately protected; configured so that only applications running on the server itself can access it. You would need to login directly on the server operating system to do what you are trying to do - either to access the database or to change the firewall settings. It is also quite possible that the database isn't actually running on the same host IP as the web site, and therefore has no port available to connect where you are looking for it.

Comment: You should use SSH and port forwarding with it to access the remote MySQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pmdba has mentioned, opening your database to the internet is a very bad idea.

Since you haven't mentioned which GNU/Linux distribution you are using and whether you use MySQL or MariaDB, I am generalizing here:

1. Configure your MySQL/MariaDB server to listen on your IP address by setting the following parameter in my.cnf:
   bind-address=IP_address or
   bind-address=0.0.0.0
   for all IP interfaces on your server.
2. Restart your database server
3. Make sure your firewall is allowing connections to tcp/3306. A command that would work is:
   iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

Check your distro documentation on how to properly add a rule for tcp/3306 in your firewall.
4. Make sure the database user is allowed to connect remotely. A generic command that would work is:
grant all privileges on database.* to 'username'@'%' identified by 'password'
for all IPs or
grant all privileges on database.* to 'username'@'DesktopIP' identified by 'password'
for enabling access only for your desktop app IP address.

Answer (score 0):

**/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** must have localhost **bind-address** commented out so:

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Create and grant permissions for user root connecting from machine **192.168.0.2** for example:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter password: <enter password>
mysql>CREATE USER 'root'@'192.168.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
mysql>GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.0.2';
mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql>exit
```